# Wrap numbers to the left of a character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

In order to add commas to a number string I'm using the following:

`someNum.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")`

I need to do one extra thing.  I need to wrap everything to the left of the comma (all numbers representing thousands or above in a `span` tag in order to color those numbers.

So if `someNum` is `42221` the output whould be `<span class="someColorClass">42</span>,221` and if `someNum` was `221` the output would be `221`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if its the most efficient way, but this works:

```
someNum.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",").replace(/^(.*),(\d+)$/,'<span class="someColorClass">$1</span>,$2')

123456789 = <span class="someColorClass">123,456</span>,789
42221 = <span class="someColorClass">42</span>,221
221 = 221
```

Comment: +1 for handing situations past the thousands. A note that neither the code from the OP nor this answer accommodate decimal places. This is strictly for whole numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you never go into the millions, after your initial replace you can just do:

```
someNum = someNum.replace(/(\d*)(,\d{3})/g, '<span class="someColorClass">$1</span>$2');
```

Comment: This solution is short-sighted.

Answer (score 0):

With two regular expressions:

```
var someNum = 12345;
var commaNum = someNum.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",").replace(/^(\d+),/,"<span>$1</span>,");
alert(commaNum);
```

It would fail highlighting the thousands if it is in the millions.

[Example](http://jsbin.com/ufozi4/edit)

If the number can be greater than 99,999 than you can use this regular expression that matches anything. It will include the commas inside of the match.

```
var someNum = 12345;
var commaNum = someNum.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",").replace(/^([\d,]+)(,\d{3})/g,"<span>$1</span>$2");
alert(commaNum);
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/ufozi4/2/edit)

Comment: `It would fail highlighting the thousands if it is in the millions.`  Then it's not a correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Different approach, checking the string length...

```
var num = "432232121678";
var num2 = "221";

function Parse(num)
{
    var thousand = num.substring(0, num.length - 3);
    if (thousand.length > 0)
    {
        return "<span class=\"someColorClass\">" + thousand.replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + "</span>," + num.substring(num.length - 3)
    }
    return num;
}

Parse(num);
Parse(num2);
```

Output

```
"<span class="someColorClass">432,232,121</span>,678"
"221"
```

[See this example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JDCbv/)